# How to print the maximum sum sub-sequence of an array with non adjacent elements?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

I've the code to find the maximum sum that can be formed with non adjacent elements of an array. How to print the elements that contributed to the sum?

```
def find_max_sum(arr): 
  incl = 0
  excl = 0
  for i in range(len(arr)): 
    if excl>incl:
      new_excl = excl
    else:
      new_excl = incl
    incl = excl + arr[i]
    excl = new_excl
  return (excl if excl>incl else incl)
```

Comment: please post code, not image of code

Comment: @adrtam Have a look at it now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you have some sample input and output. The code you posted doesn't seem to match your title.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement Kadane's algorithm but not quite in the right shape. Kadane's algorithm should look like the following:

```
def kadane(arr):
    maxseen = 0
    window = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        window = max(arr[i], window+arr[i])
        maxseen = max(window, maxseen)
    return maxseen
```

The algorithm will give you the sum (min to be 0, for a empty subarray of `arr`) but not the subarray. So you just need to remember how to come up with the solution:

```
def kadane(arr):
    if not arr:
        return []  # corner case
    maxi = wini = maxj = 0
    maxseen = 0
    winmax = 0  # max sum of window ends at winj
    for winj in range(len(arr)):
        if winmax + arr[winj] < arr[winj]:
            winmax = arr[winj]
            wini = winj
        else:
            winmax += arr[winj]
        if winmax > maxseen:
            maxi = wini
            maxj = winj
    return arr[maxi:maxj+1]
```